# C++ Inverse Kinematic Algorithm / library which includes method for IK when position of several nodes in chain known

Tags: c++, graphics, computational-geometry, robotics, inverse-kinematics

I am looking for ideally a c++ library / code (but if not at least an algorithm) that solves the IK problem for a given chain of n nodes, of which estimates for the position of k nodes (where k < n) in the chain are known.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: iterative approach is the best (analytical approach may be more precise and faster to compute but the equations behind it are very hard to derive and any change in kinematics invalidate them). you do not need to search for IK with known nodes, instead break your kinematics to sequences from known location to known location and all parts handle as simple IK problem.

Comment: btw. for iteration algorithms you just need matrix arithmetics (i usually uses for IKs transformation matrices 4x4) needed operations are matrix*matrix, matrix*vector inverse matrix. for more detailed information google some OpenGL robotic arm demo/tutorial you will get there everything you need

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using an iterative IK algorithm, such as Cyclic Coordinate Decent.